# angular unknown provider error using factory and ui.router resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm getting unknown provider error when i'm trying to use resolve from a state. The object i want returned seems to be returned correctly, so i can't really figure out what the problem is.

This is my first angular project so if I something seems wierd it probably is.

The error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=boardProvider%20%3C-%20board%20%3C-%20AppCtrl

```
var ponk = angular.module("ponk", ["ui.router", "ngResource"]);

 ponk.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
 "$locationProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,
 $locationProvider) {   
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('board', {
      url: '/b/:slug',
      templateUrl: 'views/board.html',
      controller: "AppCtrl",
      controllerAs: "pk",
      resolve: {
       board: function($stateParams, boardFactory) {
         var board = {};
         if($stateParams.slug) {
           board = boardFactory.get({slug:$stateParams.slug}).$promise;
         }
         return board;
       }
      }
   });  
 }]).run(function($state) {   $state.go('board'); });;

 ponk.factory("boardFactory", ["$http", "$resource", 
  function($http, $resource) {
   return $resource('/board/:slug', {slug:'slug'}, {update: { method: "PUT"  }}); 
 }]);

 ponk.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "boardFactory", "board",
  function($scope, $http, boardFactory, board ) {
    console.log(board);  // correct object, but error 
  }]);
```

EDIT:
discovered the above code works. The problem is when i add this to the controller:

```
var pk = this;
var pk.board = board;
```

Comment: You probably have `ng-controller="AppCtrl"` in your View - this instance of `AppCtrl` is what triggers the error, since `board` is only known to the controller defined via `$stateProvider`

Comment: no, i have already removed the ng-controller

Comment: not clear why, nothing seems irregular in code shown

Comment: discovered the code i show works, the error is thrown when i add var pk = this;
var pk.board = board; to the controller